# Open a new Form and close the other form c#

Tags: c#, forms

I'm currently working on a simple notepad. What I want to happen is that when the user clicks on the "New" button that the form that is open closes and a new form opens.
This is what I already have:

```
DialogResult newdialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to create a new file and close the existing one?", "Simple Notepad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(newdialogresult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    f1.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

The new form opens but the old one doesn't close.

Comment: It's because the `ShowDialog()` method causes the first form to 'block' while the child form is shown. Even if you used `Show()` which doesn't block then both forms would close as the child cannot exist without the parent. Are you sure you don't want to use `Hide()` on the parent form instead to make it invisible?

Comment: If that is the easiest option.

Comment: It is, see David's answer below for a slightly longer explanation. Edit: And Yogi's for a code snippet ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is to hide the main form, I agree with that. But you'd probably want to close main form when closing the child form sooner or later. To do that, you should close your main form when child form `FormClosing` event is triggered. Try with this:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.Show();
form.FormClosing += (obj, args) => { this.Close(); };
this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add another option for anyone who is interested.

In the Program.cs file you should see something like:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

This simply starts the main thread and makes the specified form visible.
The problem with this is that when you run "this.Close()" is will also terminate the main thread, so any form you are trying to open will close too.

You can do as the others suggest with "this.Hide()", however this doesn't release the resources that the current form is consuming.  So what I like to do, in the Program.cs file, is this:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var frm = new Form1();
        frm.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

This allows the main thread to continue even if the current form is closed.  You do have to be careful though and end the main thread when you want to end the program.  You can do this in the "FormClosed" event by calling "Application.Exit()".

Answer (score 0):

If you step through the code you'll see that the `this.Close();` doesn't get executed until you manually close the new window.

The [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) method is used for showing a modal dialog box.  Because of this, it does not return until the window is closed.

Depending on what else you want to do, you can either change the order of the Close/ShowDialog or change it to just `Show` instead or `Hide` the first form instead.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with David's answer, and adding to that, if you want this behavior, you can use the following code snippet insted -

```
        DialogResult newdialogresult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to create a new file and close the existing one?", "Simple Notepad", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (newdialogresult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Form2 f1 = new Form2();
            f1.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: This works thank you. Only one thing: if I now close the application completely then it keeps running as a process in the background.